# HP Color LaserJet 3700DN prints with black streaks

Tags: laser-printer

An HP Color LaserJet 3700DN prints with black interrupted streaks as shown below.

[image]

I followed steps to self clean without any improvement.

UPDATE

1. The page is in landscape, so the line appear horizontally while printing.
2. I have cleaned the transfer belt (following YouTube videos)
3. I also get a cyan block line printing down the page as well (this is solid without any breaks)

Comment: A) When you say 'followed steps to self clean', what exactly did you do? B) Do the streaks appear vertically with respect to the paper as it exits the printer, or horizontally? Without the whole page shown, it's hard to tell. Please click on edit at left above and add your responses to your original post so all can see.

Comment: Is that output a print sent from a computer, or is it a scan?

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: As [Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_printing#Malfunctions) in part (edited):

> The mechanism inside a laser printer is somewhat delicate and, once
>   damaged, often impossible to repair. The imaging unit or drum in particular 
>   is a critical component: **it must not be left exposed to ambient light for**
>   **more than a few hours, as light is what causes it to lose its charge**
>   **and will eventually wear it out**. Anything that interferes with the
>   operation of the laser such as a scrap of torn paper may prevent the
>   laser from discharging some portion of the drum, causing those areas
>   to appear as white vertical streaks. If the neutral wiper blade fails
>   to remove residual toner from the drum's surface, that toner may
>   circulate on the drum a second time, causing smears on the printed
>   page with each revolution.

Toner can be toxic; don't breathe it. Toner can have metallic particles, so don't use an ordinary vacuum; only use a vacuum designed for toner.

Let's think about what's going on in the printer, and an image (also from Wikipedia) will help:

[image]

Now, as to likely causes:

1) The black cartridge may not be loaded properly. Please take it out, and carefully reinstall the black cartridge.  Likewise, remove and reinsert the cyan cartridge. When you do so, please look closely for any excess toner. If you see it, please remove the excess gently with a lint-free cloth or wipe.

2) While you've got it open, look for tiny scraps of paper and other possible foreign objects.

3) The photosensitive mechanism may have been scratched which would require replacing the transfer unity (sometimes called the 'imaging drum').

4) The fusing subsystem may be contaminated with toner and need replacement.

Diagnosis?

A possible test to provide more information requires you print a page (a test page from the printer console is AOK) and interrupt the printing in mid cycle. Don't wear good clothes when you do this.

See p. 22 at the [User Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00224831) for a diagram of the printer and pp. 69-71 for a close-up of Tray 1.

Open up all trays to make sure no tray other than Tray 1 (#4 in diagram) is used to feed from. Put a piece of paper in Tray 1, the hand feeding tray, so you can see when the printer picks up the sheet of paper.

As the sheet of paper completely disappears into the printer, open the front door (#5 in diagram, op cit.). Printing halts because the lid's open. **Carefully**, *gently* pull the page up and out; since toner has not yet been melted onto the paper, it can easily smudge and make a mess, so be careful where the toner goes.

Since you noted the black lines are on the page, your (spendy) fuser subsystem is probably OK.

A) See #1 above.

B) Search for foreign objects (teeny tiny paper shreds may need a flashlight to be seen).

C) Obtain a toner-safe vacuum and clean the interior.

D) If neither B nor C found, it may be imaging unit damage, regrettably also spendy.

And, for reference, manuals for this printer [are found here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-color-laserjet-3700-printer-series/315849/model/315857/manuals).

Comment: Hi, I followed the steps above and the lines were on the page. Also I cleaned the toner (the cyan is leaving a solid vertical block along the left side) when I look at the toner it has the cyan powder on the toner film where the marks occur. Also in the black toner I can see some black toner residue at the very top of the film. I also printed a page with just solid CMY colours but still got the black streaks. So any updates what I should check next would be appreciated.

Comment: "The page is in landscape, so the line appear horizontally while printing." Well, that throws everything for a loop. The imager probably needs replacement. What's the distance between the black bars?